# PHP rewrap array to summarize it

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array:

```
 ["positive"]=>
     array(3) {
        [0]=>
           array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473022800000) //unix timestamp
              [1]=>
                 int(100)
     }
        [1]=>
           array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473109200000)
              [1]=>
                 int(200)
     }
        [2]=>
           array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473195600000)
              [1]=>
                 int(300)
}// etc...
 ["neutral"]=>
     array(3) {
        [0]=>
           array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473022800000) //same day as with positive
              [1]=>
                 int(400)
      }
       [1]=>
          array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473109200000)//also second same day as with positive
              [1]=>
                 int(500)
}
       [2]=>
         array(2) {
              [0]=>
                 int(1473195600000)
              [1]=>
                 int(600)
} // etc...
```

I need to rewrap it to get the following:

```
["1473022800000"]=>
array(2) {
['positive']=> (int)500 //example values, should be calculated
['neutral'] => (int)200
}
["1473109200000"]=>
array(2) {
['positive']=> (int)500
['neutral'] => (int)200
}
```

So I need to rewrap it to got not from positives or neutrals but from dates in order to sum it up this way. Any suggestions how to do that with PHP would be welcome. Thank you.

**UPD** Here is what I have tried so far

```
foreach($myarray as $key=>$val){ //getting the dates
        //var_dump($key);exit;
        for($i=0;$i<=30;++$i){
            $dates[] = $val[$i][0];
        }
    }
    $dates = array_unique(array_values($dates));
    $dates_upd = [];
    foreach($dates as $date) {
        foreach($myarray as $key=>$val){
            for($i=0;$i<=30;++$i){
                if($val[$i][0]==$date){
                    $dates_upd['date'] = $date;
                    $dates_upd['date']['total'] = $val[$i][1];//getting errors here (cant use a scalar value etc...)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what prevents you from using a `for` loop?

Comment: I cannot sum up all values correctly. First I get the array of dates and then I am trying to get the values relative to that date in foreach loop but it is giving me wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of nested foreach loops:

```
$out=[];

foreach($myarray as $key=>$subarray){

    foreach($subarray as $item){
        $date = $item[0];
        $value = $item[1];

        $out[$date][$key]=$value;
    }

}
```